# VIM - Converting a binary file back

Tags: vim

Suppose we are in some file using `VIM`. We change the file to binary mode using the command:

```
:%!xxd -b
```

How does one revert back to the previous file without pressing `u`?

Thank you! :)

Comment: @Carpetsmoker: No, it does not: `xxd` does not know how to reverse `xxd -b`.

Comment: @Amadan Ah; I assumed it would. Disappointing :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really Vim, but a solution nonetheless. Put this into your path (I call it `xxd-unbits`, but any name is as good as another) and `chmod 755 xxd-unbits`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

while (<>) {
  if (/[0-9a-f]+:((?:\s[01]{8})+)/) {
    print join('', map { chr(oct("0b$_")) } split(/\s/, substr $1, 1));
  }
}
```

Then you can do `:%!xxd-unbits`.

Comment: Thank you, I shall accept this answer, although your comment sufficed (since I ultimately wanted to know whether it was possible or not).